# Errors when opening project(s) on import (maven dep

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, apache-cloudstack

I just started with cloudstack and wanted to get the dev environment going. I have Maven installed, and using Eclipse. I've been following [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/Using+Eclipse+With+CloudStack) guide, Which seems a bit outdated, but I've been unable to find anything more recent about getting this going in Eclipse.

Versions I'm running:

```
--Eclipse 4.1
--Maven 3.6.1
--Java 1.8.0_211
--Cloudstack 4.9
```

Upon importing I'm getting 152 errors (all seem related to maven):

> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Missing artifact com.cloud.com.f5:icontrol:jar:1.0  pom.xml /cloud-plugin-network-f5    line 30 Maven Dependency Problem
>
> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact com.cloud.com.netapp:manageontap:jar:4.0  pom.xml /cloud-plugin-netapp    line
>   30    Maven Dependency Problem
>
> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact com.cloud.com.vmware:vmware-vim25:jar:6.0 pom.xml /cloud-engine-storage-integration-test  line
>   12    Maven Dependency Problem
>
> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.1:descriptor
>   (execution: default-descriptor, phase:
>   process-classes)  pom.xml /Wix-cloudstack-maven-plugin    line 16 Maven
>   Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Users.m2\repository\com\cloud\com\f5\icontrol\1.0\icontrol-1.0.jar'  cloud-plugin-network-f5     Build
>   path  Build Path Problem
>
> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type The import com.cloud.network.schema cannot be
>   resolved  BrocadeVcsApi.java  /cloud-plugin-network-vcs/src/com/cloud/network/brocade line
>   61    Java Problem

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, but may help other people trying this out for the first time.

Adding the Apache Maven repositories should allow you to build, for example I have added Maven Central and Apache Maven repositories with CloudStack 4.13.

This can be done by editing `~/.m2/settings.xml` to include mirrors, it is important to use HTTPS not HTTP as this is deprecated and will result in failures by default.

**Apache Repository Entry**

Entry to be added to configuration.

```
    <mirror>
      <id>Apache HTTPS</id>
      <mirrorOf>apache</mirrorOf>
      <name>Apache (HTTPS)</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
```

**Example**

Mirrors only entry for user.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>Central HTTPS</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Maven Central (HTTPS)</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>Apache HTTPS</id>
      <mirrorOf>apache</mirrorOf>
      <name>Apache (HTTPS)</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```